# Cannot create Bean in Spring Boot when use autowired

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, spring-bean

I have a *AppController* class where I autowired the *PluginManager* as:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class AppController {
    private final PluginManager pluginManager;

    @Autowired
    public AppController(PluginManager pluginManager) {
        this.pluginManager = pluginManager;
    }
    return "app";
}
```

The *PluginManager* bean configuration as:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public PluginManager pluginManager(@Value("${application.service.defs}") String pattern) {
        return new PluginManager(pattern);
    }
}
```

The *${application.service.defs}* is a string where I get in the *application.yml* file.

The *PluginManager* object as:

```
public class PluginManager {

    private final List<String> serviceDefPatterns = new ArrayList<>();
    public PluginManager(String serviceDefPattern) {
        this.serviceDefPatterns.addAll(Arrays.asList(serviceDefPattern.split(",")));
    }
}
```

When I run the cmd as *mvn spring-boot: run*, the errors was occurred:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'appController' defined in file [D:\Workspace\wae-thesis\wae-thesis-application\targe
t\classes\wae\thesis\indiv\app\controller\AppController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.facto
ry.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pluginManager' defined in class path resource [wae/thesis/indiv/app/config/AppConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory
method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [wae.thesis.indiv.core.plugins.PluginManager]: Factory method 'pluginM
anager' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1193) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEAS
E.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE
.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.
3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.
7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.
RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3
.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
        at wae.thesis.indiv.app.Application.main(Application.java:13) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:527) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_121]
```

When I run with the command *mvn spring-boot:run*, the problems occured. However, when I use IntelliJ IDE to run the app, everything is ok, the problem is disappear.

Any help will be appreciate. Thank you.

Comment: `pattern` is obviously null hence the NPE, you might be missing some "property definition" (i.e. where the `@Value` comes from)

Comment: Try enabling auto scan configuration.

Comment: @RC: I use the annotaion Value to assign the value into pattern field, the value comes from the application.yml file

Comment: I copied your code and can't seem to replicate the issue. It worked fine with both IntelliJ and `mvn spring-boot:run` for me. Where is you application.yml located and what's in it? Also, are you including something like `snakeyaml` so your application.yml is dealt with correctly?

Comment: Well, how to say, my full source code is long that why I didn't attach whole code here. However, I found out that in the Bean object class (aka.PluginManager) if I add a field such as `private final ServiceBehavior serviceBehavior` and then I initialized this object in the Bean constructor, the errors immediately happened. Maybe it is my mistake when I create and config the Bean. Anyways, thank for your cmt.